# Auto scheduler wont wake pc windows 10

Tags: scheduled-tasks

Ok, so i have been struggling to get the task scheduler of windows 10 to wake my pc up when in sleep mode. I am using the sleep button from the start>shutdown>sleep or a button on my keyboard.

I have set up the task to run a program daily at 7am, run with highest privileges, run weather someone is logged in or not, wake this pc.

I then have checked my pc's power options to ensure that enable wake timers is on and it is.

I have checked all the things i know of. What am i missing?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Wake up problems can happen because of different reasons.  In this post of Microsoft forum you can see some problems solved about it, see if someting there helps you :

https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/windows-10-task-scheduler-doesnt-wake-the-computer/57975139-36a9-4398-9259-38172aae023b

Comment: thanks larry, im reading it now, and it seems that i have done all those options they suggest.  I feel at a loss with this haha.  I also read that the readdll file that windows uses to put the pc to sleep has a bug. does the actual sleep button in start menu use the readdll script? thanks